# How to get VSCode to not check other .ts files in directory for variable conflicts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a React app with a directory of TypeScript scripts which I use to run admin tasks, etc.
I execute them with npm scripts in the `package.json` file, e.g.

```
"ts001test": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --skip-project scripts/ts_codeExamples/ts001_test.ts"
```

which works fine. (`--skip-project` prevents ts-node rom loading the `.tsconfig` file)

However, when two of these scripts have the same variable, **VSCode complains that I cannot redeclare the same variable that is in another file**.

How can I tell VSCode to treat each of these TypeScript files with their own individual scope and not look in other files to see if variables have been used elsewhere?

[image]

Comment: Use tsconfig.json to exclude those files/folders?

Comment: No, I added `"scripts/ts_codeExamples"` under `exclude` in `tsconfig.json`, closed and opened VSCode, and it still looks for and finds the duplicate variables.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by putting the following line at the beginning of each TypeScript script:

```
export {};
```

as mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/@muravitskiy.mail/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-varname-how-to-fix-b1c3d9cc8206):

> TypeScript decided to solve the problem by simply stating that a module is any file which contains an import or export.

Comment: TypeScript should have made a less ridiculous assumption since so many people are still using the commonjs module system. 